# Where is the windows app installed + .NET + VS2005

Tags: .net, publish, windows

I deployed a windows application in the following website http://StagingServer/MyProgs/MPP/ on my intranet site, using the Publish Wizard of VS 2005...  I accepted all defaults (including Offline support).

My users were also able to install the same from the path specified.  But when I try to find out the exact location of the EXE in the client, it is not pointing anywhere.  I also tried a file search but in vain.

Initially I thought the application is running from the server itself, but we were able to start the app, even when the server is down (ofcourse it takes more time to search for updates initially).

Ps : The app is showing even in control panel...

- Raja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you deploying you application using ClickOnce?  If so, on an XP machine you'll find the installation here:

C:\Documents and Settings\userprofile\Local Settings\Apps

Answer (score 1):

ClickOnce will install files in one of his folders, and will have a sort of sandbox for data files (the special folder appdata will point to something different than the default user's one).
Of course an app can not run "remotely"... If you choose not to allow offline usage, ClickOnce will not run the app unless it can reach the server. You can check My.Application.Deployment object (in VB.Net) for deployment information.